# IntelliJ IDEA: keyboard shortcut ALT+INSERT for Generate

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Intellij: keyboard shortcut ALT+INSERT for generate ...

For HP laptop, press ALT + INS(print sc), nothing happens.
The key is marked as `ins/print sc`. There is no other key especially for INSERT. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some other keyboard shortcut at File | Settings | Keymap for the **Generate** action:

[image: Generate]